# Taking a date from text file and putting it in a date time picker

Tags: vb.net, date, text-files, datetimepicker

Please can you help me, I want to save a date to a text file after its been picked from the date time picker and then when the program is loaded again I'd like the date to be in the date time picker.

```
    FileReader = New StreamReader("datefile.txt")
    Output = FileReader.ReadLine()
    FileReader.Close()


    Dim OutputDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(Output, "dd/MM/yyyy",
               System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    DateTimePicker1.Value = OutputDate
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FileWriter = New StreamWriter("datefile.txt", False)
    FileWriter.WriteLine(DateTimePicker1.Value)
    FileWriter.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: And what problem are you having?

Comment: I guess you've got a problem parsing the date. Try changing what you write to the file: `FileWriter.WriteLine(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: The problem I'm having is getting the date from my text file to the date time picker. I tried adding that new bit of code but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Does it throw any exception? If it does, edit your question and paste it

Comment: I know the date is saving because I can put it into a label.

Comment: Try to set `Output` to a valid date,e.g. `Output  = "29/11/2017"` just before the ParseExact line and see if it works.

Comment: I've fixed it now :) I just got rid of " Dim OutputDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(Output, "dd/MM/yyyy",
               System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    DateTimePicker1.Value = OutputDate" and used DateTimePicker1.Value = OutputDate

Comment: Thanks for your help Pikoh :)

Comment: Most likely the contents of the file you were trying to load contained the time as well as the date. I'd strongly recommend you use `Option Strict` because your current solution depends on implicit type conversion from `String` to `Date`.

Comment: @SSS I will have a look into that, I'm always up for learning something new and making my work better :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "M"s are the right case - uppercase M means "Month", lowercase "m" means minute. Also try some error-trapping, and specifying the full path:

```
  Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim FileReader As StreamReader
    Try
      FileReader = New StreamReader("C:\junk\datefile.txt")
      Dim Output As String = FileReader.ReadLine()
      FileReader.Close()
      Dim OutputDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(Output, "dd/MM/yyyy",
               System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
      DateTimePicker1.Value = OutputDate
    Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
    Dim FileWriter As New StreamWriter("C:\Junk\datefile.txt", False)
    FileWriter.WriteLine(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    FileWriter.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)